# How can I make ensime show all compilation errors?

Tags: scala, playframework, ensime

I'm doing Scala web development using the Play framework's scala module, and using Emacs+Ensime to edit the code. Sometimes even when Ensime shows no errors, Play will still show a compilation error for a .scala file (like a type parameter mistake, or even a typo'd override, which is such a basic error).

How can I make ensime show all compilation errors that Play would show?

I'm using Scala 2.8.1, with ensime_2.8.2-SNAPSHOT-0.5.1 (which seemed like the best of the available options when I downloaded it).

Comment: you mean in scala templates (view files) or the scala code (controllers/ models etc) ? ensime should catch errors if there are in the scala code, not sure about the templates, because play has a custom parser for the templates that generates code before it can be compiled. If you see problems compiling the code, please raise issues on [github](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime) and I am sure they will be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is supported, because ensime only uses the presentation compiler, which does not do all the checks that the full scalac compiler does.